# Does upgrading the Sacred Chime affect miracle damage and healing effectiveness?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I know that miracle damage is affected by faith, but does upgrading the sacred chime also increase the damage of miracles and the effectiveness of healing miracles? The item status says it inflicts lightning and dark damage and this stat is increased by upgrading the chime, but does this mean the actual miracle damage or the damage done by its melee attack? Do any of those stats have an effect on healing miracles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, upgrading your charm affects the potency of miracles. This means that the **damage** of miracles such as Lightning Spear increase and the **healing** of miracles such as Heal also increases.

It's more effective to upgrade your charm than it is to add 1 point into Faith. Upgrading your charm once will add 20-40 damage to your Lightning Spear which is significantly more than adding 1 point into Faith.

In short; upgrade your charm to increase miracle potency

(Upgrading your charm also increases the melee attack if you are so inclined to bonk someone over the head with it)

To reflect the queries in the comments, I have tested the healing and it does increase the amount healed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Are you sure that it also increases healing effectiveness, do you have a source for that or is it your personal observation, because the stat numbers that change by upgrading the chime are the attack bonuses for lightning and dark. Since there is no specific number for healing, I don't know if the lightning attack bonus influences healing as well as it does the attacking miracles like lightning spear.

Comment: Does infusing a weapon with magic have any effect on sorceries?

Comment: @Mondrianaire I doubt that, I think it just adds the elemental damage stat to the weapon when it strikes. Since you don't use sorceries with the infused weapon, it won't have an effect on that. But anyway, that's a whole other question than mine ;)

Comment: Infusing your Staff with Magic will increase the potency of your Spells.
Infusing your Charm with Lightning will increase the potency of your Lightning Miracles.
Infusing your Charm/Staff with Dark will increase the potency of your Dark Spells/Hexes.