# Does infusing chimes affect spell damage?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I saw on [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160947/does-upgrading-the-sacred-chime-affect-miracle-damage-and-healing-effectiveness) that upgrading chimes does indeed affect miracle damage. My question is will infusing my chime with lightning add to my lightning based spell damage as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, infusing your charm with lightning will increase the lightning damage dealt

Comment: It's not that I don't trust strangers on the internet but, do you have any data, or a link to back this up? I really do want you to be right.

Comment: Personal experience, here is a link from reddit http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/2152y8/make_sure_to_infuse_your_charmsstaffs/

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to finish the Darkdivers covenant...